# Control of Firefox's Form Recovery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, firefox

I have a page that contains multiple checkbox input elements.  Toggling these alter the appearance of the page in a way that can only be done in Javascript.

My problem arises when you close and reopen the page.  A brief (seemingly inconsistent) moment after the page loads, Firefox restores the state of the checkboxes without raising their onchange events.

Is there a way to determine when Firefox recovers these elements, or at the very least, is there any way to disable this functionality without requiring the users to change their browser settings?

I am also using jQuery, in case that has anything that can help.

Using `autocomplete="off"` on the inputs has no effect.

Comment: Probably best to just reset the form when the load event fires - `document.forms[0].reset()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just need to fire the change handlers, to match the page's state to the user's last preference (which seems like a good idea), then something like this should do the trick. :

```
$(window).load ( function () {
    $('input:checked').change ();
} );
```

[**See the demo at jsBin**](http://jsbin.com/orozic/2).

Comment: Oh wow, I noticed it was happening a while after document.ready, and never tried the load event.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

"Toggling these alter the appearance of the page"

There's your problem. The page should depend on the *state* of the toggle, not be changed when they are toggled. I too have grappled with the "change" event and browser history. Instead of fighting it, embrace it as free storage of user specific data. Draw the page based on the input status, even if you think you know what it *should* be.

If you post some specific code I could suggest alterations.

Comment: Basically what happens when you toggle these boxes is this... one element is permanently stricken from the DOM, another element is hidden using an animation, (or unhidden if all boxes are cleared) HTML gets written to a couple DIV to load Flash objects, and various DIVs (depending on checked boxes) get resized and positioned so that they may all fit on the screen at the same time.  This page is designed to never use more or less space than the window provides. (Similar to Grooveshark in that way.)

Comment: I'm just saying that the two functionalities should be separate. Use a "change" event, but have it call a "stateOfToggle" function which does the actual manipulation. Then you can trigger the same handler on document.ready and recreate the effect of the user's checkboxes.